# Multi Tenant Snowflake Datasource using Hikari from Spring creating more and more threads causing memory issue later

Tags: memory-leaks, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, hikaricp

I have Spring web app on tomcat and it connects to both myql and snowflake depending on the configuration for which i am using AbstractRoutingDataSource and putting all the datasources in a map. I am finding that the number of threads are getting created by the connection and it is causing memory issue. Not able to know whether this is Hikari Database connection concurrency issue or the issue with the underlying snowflake driver. If i replace the snowflake datasource with other mysql datasource then everything works fine.

The code for the snowflake datasource is given below:

```
public DataSource getSFDataSource(CommonTenantEntity tenant) {
        //it's assumed its snoflake at this point
        HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
        config.setDriverClassName(<Datsource drive name>);
        config.setJdbcUrl(<URL to Snowflake>);
        config.setUsername(<Username>);
        config.setPassword(<Password>);
        config.setPoolName(org.springframework.util.StringUtils.isEmpty(SUFFIX_SF) ?
        config.setMaximumPoolSize(<Pool size>);
        config.setConnectionTimeout(<Timeout>);
        config.addDataSourceProperty("cachePrepStmts", "true");
        config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSize", "250");
        config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", "2048");
        config.addDataSourceProperty("zeroDateTimeBehavior", "convertToNull");
        config.addDataSourceProperty("useLegacyDatetimeCode", "false");
        config.setLeakDetectionThreshold(3000);
        config.setIdleTimeout(3000);
       config.addDataSourceProperty("hibernate.physical_naming_strategy", "org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.OrgSFPhysicalNamingStrategyImpl");
       config.addDataSourceProperty("hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy", "CustomNamingStrategy");
        return new HikariDataSource(config);
    }
```

The thread dump observed during this is as below:

```
    "integration-snowflake-4 housekeeper" - Thread t@122
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING
        at java.base@11.0.16/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for <6cb5eb65> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
        at java.base@11.0.16/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:234)
        at java.base@11.0.16/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2123)
        at java.base@11.0.16/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1182)
        at java.base@11.0.16/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:899)
        at java.base@11.0.16/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1054)
        at java.base@11.0.16/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1114)
        at java.base@11.0.16/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base@11.0.16/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"integration-snowflake-4 connection adder" - Thread t@123
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.base@11.0.16/java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.base@11.0.16/java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:115)
        at java.base@11.0.16/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168)
        at java.base@11.0.16/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:140)
        at java.base@11.0.16/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:478)
        at java.base@11.0.16/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.readHeader(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:472)
        at java.base@11.0.16/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.bytesInCompletePacket(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:70)
        at java.base@11.0.16/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readApplicationRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1454)
        at java.base@11.0.16/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(SSLSocketImpl.java:1065)
        at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:137)
        at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.fillBuffer(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:153)
        at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.readLine(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:280)
        at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:138)
        at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:56)
        at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:259)
        at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:163)
        at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:157)
        at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:273)
        at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
        at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:272)
        at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
        at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
        at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
        at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
        at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
        at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108)
        at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.RestRequest.execute(RestRequest.java:160)
        at net.snowflake.client.core.HttpUtil.executeRequestInternal(HttpUtil.java:614)
        at net.snowflake.client.core.HttpUtil.executeRequest(HttpUtil.java:559)
        at net.snowflake.client.core.HttpUtil.executeGeneralRequest(HttpUtil.java:526)
        at net.snowflake.client.core.SessionUtil.newSession(SessionUtil.java:586)
        at net.snowflake.client.core.SessionUtil.openSession(SessionUtil.java:284)
        at net.snowflake.client.core.SFSession.open(SFSession.java:446)
        - locked <381ec49c> (a net.snowflake.client.core.SFSession)
        at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.DefaultSFConnectionHandler.initialize(DefaultSFConnectionHandler.java:104)
        at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.DefaultSFConnectionHandler.initializeConnection(DefaultSFConnectionHandler.java:79)
        at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeConnectionV1.initConnectionWithImpl(SnowflakeConnectionV1.java:116)
        at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeConnectionV1.<init>(SnowflakeConnectionV1.java:96)
        at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeDriver.connect(SnowflakeDriver.java:164)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:359)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:470)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCreator.call(HikariPool.java:733)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCreator.call(HikariPool.java:712)
        at java.base@11.0.16/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base@11.0.16/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base@11.0.16/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base@11.0.16/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - locked <5c5da1e> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)

        - locked <761970bf> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync)
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What about collecting a heapdump? You can use Eclipse MAT to analyze the heapdump and see who/what consumes the heap.

Comment: @Sergiu, Its byte[] i seen earlier. May be i will try to get the complete snap of that

Comment: No of threads are increasing crazily here. I think when Hikari trying to create a new connection it is not able to close the previous datasource or its connection properly. May be underlying issue with the snowflake driver implementation or like that